# Python FTP hang

Tags: timeout, freeze, connection-timeout

Say I want to use FTP in Python using the ftplib.  I begin with this:

```
from ftplib import ftp
ftp = FTP('10.10.10.151')
```

If the FTP server is not online, however, it will hang right there indefinitely.  The only thing that can kick it out is a keyboard interrupt as far as I know.  I've tried this:

```
ftp.connect('10.10.10.151','21', 5)
```

With the five being a five second timeout.  But the problem here is that I do not know of any way to use that line without first assigning ftp something.  But if the server is offline, then the "ftp =" line will hang.  So what use is ftp.connect()'s timeout function?!?

Does anybody know a workaround or anything?  Is there a way to time out the "ftp = FTP(xxx)" command that I haven't found?  Thanks.

I'm using Python 2.7 on Linux Mint.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `connect()` is redundant since `FTP()` method [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP) states:

```
When host is given, the method call connect(host) is made.
```

Also, since Python 2.6, `FTP()` does have a *timeout* parameter:

```
class ftplib.FTP([host[, user[, passwd[, acct[, timeout]]]]])
 The optional timeout parameter specifies a timeout in seconds for blocking operations like the connection attempt (if is not specified, the global default timeout setting will be used).
```